# ActionBarPullToRefresh Progress Bar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, pull-to-refresh

I'm implementing Chris Banes ActionBarPullToRefresh in my project. It works just fine but my problem is the blue progress bar animation does not go away after the refresh has ended.. Any ideas? Is there an option I'm missing? I know it's not my getAccountTransactions async task because I completely removed that and the problem persisted.

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(activity)

            // We need to insert the PullToRefreshLayout into the Fragment's ViewGroup
            .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)
                    // We need to mark the ListView and it's Empty View as pull-able
                    // This is because they are not direct children of the ViewGroup

            .theseChildrenArePullable(getListView(), getListView().getEmptyView())
                    // Set the OnRefreshListener

            .options(Options.create().refreshOnUp(true).build())

            .listener(new OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefreshStarted(View view) {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, "Refreshing :)"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                    getAccountTransactions trans = new getAccountTransactions();
                    trans.execute();
                }

            })
                    // Finally commit the setup to our PullToRefreshLayout
            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
    //mPullToRefreshLayout.
}
```

xml page...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Acts as a framelayout so that pull to refresh can be implemented-->
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Desc"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Amt"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#33b5e6"
        android:dividerHeight="2px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

There is a method you can call after you do your action in your listener that alerts the pull to refresh layout that your action is completed.. adding

```
// Notify PullToRefreshLayout that the refresh has finished
 mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
```

solved my problem